# <frameset> with <frame> not working in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: html, frameset

I'm trying to create a full page iframe. It's displaying on Safari, but not on Chrome and Firefox.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dashboard!</title>
</head>
    <frameset>
        <frame src="http://www.freedom.tm/auth/limebukkit+apply">
    </frameset>
    <noframes>
        Your browser does not support frames. Please click <a href="http://www.freedom.tm/auth/limebukkit+apply"> here </a> to be redirected automatically
    </noframes>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me, no problem in Chromium browser with your code and a working site referenced in there.

Comment: Ah, must be something on my side. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your browser's developer console.

> Refused to display '`https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DelegateAccountSelector?continue=https://ac…_type%3Donline%26approval_prompt%3Dauto%26state%3D1613182848&btmpl=authsub`' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

`http://www.freedom.tm/auth/limebukkit+apply` redirects to Google to handle logging in and Google won't let you put their pages in frames.